# A field in DataGridView control auto-decrements

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a DataGridView control bound to an mdb file. The first field is id. I've not made the mdb file. When in the program I see that whenever I come to create a new row the id gets -1. if I leave it and go to another row indicating I'm not going to add a new row and return to it (last row) the field gets -2. When I repeatedly do this I see that the value gets decremented each time.

At first the mdb file has two rows with ids 1 and 2. If it's defined as an auto-increment field, it must be initialized with 3 each time, not to decrement each time.

Since this is my first try with DataGridView, please inform me about this behavior and how can i fix this?

Comment: What does '910428' refer to here?

Comment: it's just for myself to know the date of post :)

Comment: You need to provide some code to get an answer. This will have nothing to do with the DataGridView unless you have changed some code. Probably there is something in the mdb definition of how you are opening it.

Comment: before any code is provided, please let me know how can i check that the field is setup to auto-decrement when i open the MDB file in access?

Comment: I have no idea sorry - haven't even looked at access let alone coded against it in years and years. If you need to know that, ask as another question.

Comment: indeed there's no special code. i the design mode, i've inserted a DataGridView control into the form and defined the MDB file as the data source for it.